# Iframe target parent not working

Tags: php, html, iframe

I'm doing a website that is a more actual menu than the actual one, and I'm just using iframes to organize the content.

When you click on an item of the menu, it has a link to the same webpage with a get parameter, where there is a switch option that read the param and print the correct iframe.

The problem is that when I go to some menu and this menu has different options, it is printed the first menu with some link and, when I clik on one of these links, I'm redirected to correct website but in a new window. Is it possible to be always in the same window?

I have just tried with  or "_self" but it is not working. The server is the same for both websites but they are located on different folders, so I'm using absolute paths because is easier (My idea is to implement it and later improve step by step).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update what is inside an given iFrame, than the iFrame needs a name (be sure to use a unique name) and the link that's supposed to update your iFrame needs a target.

[Here's an example](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_iframe.asp):

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>
```

If you want to update the parent page (the one, that has the iFrames in it), then use `target="_parent"` within the `<a>`-tag.

_self is the frame or window, that the link is called from.